# passport-local strange error: "Expected a `length` to be a non-negative finite number"

Tags: node.js, mongoose, passport-local

I'm developing a Node server app that can register new users with this end point:

```
// 'Create a new account
api.post('/register', (req, res) => {
    try {

        // Create new user and register it with passport
        let newUser = new AccountModel({ 
            username: req.body.email,

            verificationToken: "",

            active: false,
            displayName: "Uknown",
            profileImageUrl: "",
            profileImagePubid: "",
            likes: [],
            nation: req.body.nation,
            points: 0
        });

        AccountModel.register(newUser, req.body.password, function(err, account) {
            if(err){ // this check if the user name already exists.
                writeLog("ERROR", req.url + " - Error: -1 " + err.message);
                res.status(500).send( { error: err.message, errnum: -1 } );
                return;
            }

            passport.authenticate('local', { session: false })(req, res, (err)  => {
                if(err){
                    writeLog("ERROR",req.url + " - Error: -2 " + err.message);
                    res.status(500).send( { error: err.message, errnum: -2 } );
                    return; 
                }

                // Generate the verification token
                var strVer = crypto(16);

                // Update user information with the verification token
                account.verificationToken = strVer;
                account.active = false
                account.save( (err, account) => {
                    if(err) {
                        writeLog("ERROR",req.url + " - Error: -3 " + err.message);
                        res.status(500).send( { error: err.message, errnum: -3 } );
                        return;
                    }

                    // Send an email for account verification
                    var dataToSend = {
                        "user_email": account.username,
                        "verification_token": strVer
                    };
                    sendEmailSendgrid(account.username, process.env.SENDGRID_TEMPLATE_VER_EMAIL, "Confirm your email address please!", dataToSend);

                    writeLog("INFO",req.url + " - Successfully created new account - " + account.username);
                    res.status(200).send( { message : "Successfully created new account", token: strVer } );
                    return;
                });
            });
        });

    } catch (err) {
        writeLog("ERROR",req.url + " - Unexpected error registering the new account. " + err.message);
        res.status(500).send( { error: "Unexpected error registering the new account." + err.message } );
        return;
    }
});
```

This create the new user and then send an email to it via sendgrid.com
But I'm getting back this error:

```
[2019-08-19T13:30:46.148] [ERROR] default - /register - Error: -2 Expected a `length` to be a non-negative finite number
```

and I'm not able to understand why! 
The account is created properly in the mongo DB!

The post params example:

```
{
"email": "myemail@gmail.com", "nation": "US", "password": "apassword"
}
```

Here the account model

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import passportLocalMongoose from 'passport-local-mongoose';
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

let Account = new Schema ({
   active: { type: Boolean, default: false },
   displayName: { type: String, default: "Uknown" },
   verificationToken: { type: String, default: "" },
   profileImageUrl: { type: String, default: "" },
   profileImagePubid: { type: String, default: "" },
   likes: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Spot" }],
   nation: { type: String, default: "ND" },
   points: { type: Number, default: 0 }
});

Account.plugin(passportLocalMongoose); // attach the passport-local-mongoose plugin
module.exports = mongoose.model('Account', Account);
```

Thank you very much in advance for the help!!!

Answer (score 0):

it's a Typo on this line :

```
    passport.authenticate('local', { session: false })(req, res, (err)  => {
```

Try like this :

```
     passport.authenticate('local', { session: false } ,(err, user, info)  => {
```

Comment: thank you. No more the error but now the request goes in time out.

Comment: Probably is the crypto(16) function...could be?